# storing and retrieving different language characters in Postgres and JSP

Tags: java, postgresql, jsp

How to store and retrieve data stored in different languages (Could be Chinese, Hindi, French or any other which has peculiar characters in it).

Comment: Just configure everything to use a charset which supports all those characters, for example UTF-8. If you struggle at a specific point, please ask a more specific question.

Comment: Hi Balu, Thanks for the idea but let me give you a clear picture of my requirement. All the labels in the application would be displayed in hindi and user enters the data in textboxes in hindi only. Then I need to save the entered data into postgres sql and retrieve the text in hindi for displaying it to the end user. Am i clear, please let me know for any addition inputs. Your help is highly appreciated !!

Comment: Just configure everything to use a charset which supports all those characters, for example UTF-8.

Answer (score 1):

- Create the database in PostgreSQL using UTF-8 as the character set
- Make sure all your web pages are encoded using UTF-8 (See this [link](http://www.w3.org/International/questions/qa-changing-encoding) for examples), this is mainly done using something like `<meta charset="UTF-8">` in your JSP pages
- Make sure all your HTML forms have an `accept-charset="UTF-8"` attribute
- Make sure that all your servlet container/application container sends and receives the data properly in UTF-8

Comment: Meta tag is ignored when request is served over HTTP. Accept-charset is ignored by all browsers other than MSIE when the charset is set in response header and even then it is doing it faulty.

Comment: Thanks guys, I will work on it and let you know. Thanks to both of you.

Comment: Hi Guys, i worked as mentioned by you. But its giving me some weird characters. I have set everything to UTF 8

Comment: Well, then apparently you forgot something somewhere (my list is by no means complete!). But without the code there is not much we can do to help you, sorry.

Comment: I got the answer for this from another genetleman !!! need to modify the action form settings too http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7386398/insert-hindi-values-in-postgres-database-from-java/7386655#7386655 Thanks everyone !!!